# how to remove view from superview in apple watch / watchkit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, apple-watch, removechild

to use  same visibility functions in android such as

```
1) android:visibility="gone" // used to hide the control and as well as space
  (or)
  CONTROLNAME.setVisibility(View.GONE);
2)  android:visibility="invisible" // used to hide the control but it will take space
  (or)
  CONTROLNAME.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

which is in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22705333/1880500)
for apple watch application

i have tried code below

```
splashscreenImage.removeFromSuperView()
```

and

```
[self.splashscreenImage addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.captchaView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
```

also

```
[splashscreenImage removeFromSuperview]
```

non of above has worked for me. Please tell me code to remove view from super for a class which is extended from WKInterfaceController.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to set the hidden property to true?

Comment: i didnt know there was such a property, trying right away.

Comment: thank you, its working for me, but i am still waiting for answer to remove view programitically

Comment: for my problem's solution ; in willActivate func {var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: Selector("splashscreenAlpha"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}, and as  func splashscreenAlpha() { splashscreenImage.setHidden(true)
}

Comment: Could be that you can't remove it programatically, because WatchKit is very storyboard centric. File a radar if you think this should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WatchKit you can not remove the objects programmatically.

You can use [setHidden:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceObject_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceObject/setHidden:) property

> Hides or shows the interface object in your user interface.
>
> func setHidden(_ hidden: Bool)
>
> A Boolean value indicating the visibility of the object. Specify true
>   to hide the object. Specify false to show it.
>
> Discussion
>
> When you hide or show an object in your interface, WatchKit makes a
>   note to update the layout during the next refresh cycle. During that
>   cycle, WatchKit adjusts the layout to display only the currently
>   visible objects.

Reference Questions :

[Can I create a WatchKit app without a storyboard (entirely in code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015714/can-i-create-a-watchkit-app-without-a-storyboard-entirely-in-code)

[Create imageView programmatically in Watch Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658498/create-imageview-programmatically-in-watch-kit)